# Unknown web method Delete_Local_ABC. Parameter name: methodName in ASP.NET app

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, sql-server-2012-express

I have been getting this error on my following code, which basically initiates the `POST` request as
`ABC.ascx`

```
var ABCid = $(aTag).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebMethods.aspx/Delete_Local_ABC",
            data: "{'id':'" + ABCid + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: successdelete_ABC,
            error: Errordelete_ABC
        });
    }
```

**`WebMethods.aspx.cs`**

```
[WebMethod]
public static int Delete_Local_ABC(string id)
{
    ABC objABC = new ABC();
    objABC.ABC_ID = Convert.ToInt32(id);
    // call business manager
    try
    {
        BusinessManager businessManager = new BusinessManager();
        businessManager.ManageABC(objABC, OperationTypes.Validate);
        return 1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

and I am calling following method in `BusinessManager.cs`

```
....
case OperationTypes.Validate: 
                    obj.deleteLocalABC();
                    break;
...
```

and `ABC.cs`

```
public bool deleteLocalABC()
        {
            string query = "DELETE FROM TBL_ABC WHERE ABC_ID ='" + this.ABC_ID + "'";
            _dbManager.executeQuery(query);

            return true;
        }
```

I have tried all the solutions available online but nothing is working. This code works perfectly with `Visual Studio` but not on main deployment.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: You said the method is in `WebMethods.cs`. did you mean `WebMethods.ascx.cs`? There seems to be some confusion about where your method is and what you are calling. your ajax is looking for `WebMethods.aspx`. (maybe that's normal? i haven't put a web method in a user control before.) Try moving the web method into the .aspx code behind.

Comment: @PromodPiyatissa Unknown web method Delete_Local_ABC. Parameter name: methodName in ASP.NET app is the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
[WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
```

instead of just `[WebMethod]`.
I hope your method work fine after that addition.