# How to send to controller with Ajax?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to send the query to the controller with an Ajax query, but I couldn't. I don't know much, I work as an intern. Before doing it, I looked at how to send data with ajax query, but it didn't work. I will be grateful if you could help me.

my .aspx code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function customActionOn(itemStockCode) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/SAPManagement/SAPUpdate.aspx/CustomActionOn',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                data: "{'itemStockCode': '"+itemStockCode+"'}",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            });
        }

        function customActionOff(itemStockCode) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/SAPManagement/SAPUpdate.aspx/CustomActionOff',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                data: "{'itemStockCode': '" + itemStockCode + "'}",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            });
        }
    </script>


<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="GetDeatils" ShowFilterIcon="false" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderText="Open and Close The Product On The Web" FilterControlWidth="10px" AutoPostBackOnFilter="false">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%--<asp:Button CommandName="GetDeatils" ID="GetDeatils2" OnClientClick='<%# "javascript:openwin("+Eval("ItemStockCode").ToString()+")" %>'
                                    runat="server" Text="Detay"></asp:Button>--%>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-block green" Text="Open" OnClientClick='<%# "customActionOn("+Eval("ItemStockCode").ToString()+")" %>'></asp:Button>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-block red" Text="Close" OnClientClick='<%# "customActionOff("+Eval("ItemStockCode").ToString()+")" %>'></asp:Button>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

.aspx.cs code:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public void CustomActionOn(string itemStockCode)
    {
        products = new LogicRules.B2B.BL_Product().GetAllProductsForSAPUpdate().OrderBy(x => x.ItemName).ToList();
        var selectedProduct = products.Where(x => x.ItemStockCode == itemStockCode).FirstOrDefault();
        selectedProduct.PublishOnB2B = true;
        new Core.Log.ArkLogs().WriteProductUpdateLog(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectedProduct), User.Identity.GetUserId<int>(), "Product", "ISBN", selectedProduct.ItemStockCode);
        var retValues = new SapFunction.ProductFunction().updateProduct(selectedProduct);
    }


    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public void CustomActionOff(string itemStockCode)
    {
        products = new LogicRules.B2B.BL_Product().GetAllProductsForSAPUpdate().OrderBy(x => x.ItemName).ToList();
        var selectedProduct = products.Where(x => x.ItemStockCode == itemStockCode).FirstOrDefault();
        selectedProduct.PublishOnB2B = false;
        new Core.Log.ArkLogs().WriteProductUpdateLog(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectedProduct), User.Identity.GetUserId<int>(), "Product", "ISBN", selectedProduct.ItemStockCode);
        var retValues = new SapFunction.ProductFunction().updateProduct(selectedProduct);
    }
```

I can't send data to the controller this way. I am getting the itemstockcode value correctly. But the data does not go to the controls. I will be grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your input model, instead of getting string, get an object

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public void CustomActionOff(ItemStockCodeModel itemStockCodeRequest)
{
    products = new LogicRules.B2B.BL_Product().GetAllProductsForSAPUpdate().OrderBy(x => x.ItemName).ToList();
    var selectedProduct = products.Where(x => x.ItemStockCode == itemStockCodeRequest.itemStockCode).FirstOrDefault();
    selectedProduct.PublishOnB2B = false;
    new Core.Log.ArkLogs().WriteProductUpdateLog(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectedProduct), User.Identity.GetUserId<int>(), "Product", "ISBN", selectedProduct.ItemStockCode);
    var retValues = new SapFunction.ProductFunction().updateProduct(selectedProduct);
}
```

and define a model in the namespace

```
public class ItemStockCodeModel
{
      public string ItemStockCode{set;get;}
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much, I changed the controller as you said. Nothing changed. There seems to be a problem with the Ajax query. I print a message if the ajax query returns successful or unsuccessful. It happens unsuccessfully. Error status:500 statusText: It gives the error as "Internal Server Error".

Comment: oh in that case, there is some problem in your action, you can set breakpoint to debug it

Comment: I'm watching one by one. It crashes when it comes to the url in the Ajax query. When I look at the response text in the error, I see that it gives the error  "Unknown web method CustomActionOn". "Parameter name: methodName". But I don't think there is anything wrong with the url.

Comment: does this issue help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49268186/unknown-web-method-delete-local-abc-parameter-name-methodname-in-asp-net-app

Comment: I just retested it now. Normally the ajax query is correct. The problem comes from here. It gives an error when you give it as public void in the controller. I think giving static is mandatory. But when I give static, I can't pull the data in the controller. So it is mandatory to give as follows:

"public static string CustomActionOn(ItemStockCodeModel itemStockCodeRequest)"